# How to Parse Json grandchild in VB.NET Newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, descendant, grandchild

I am having trouble showing tongits,black jack, 21 in a Listbox

I can only show favorite game, game in a Listbox

and also how can I count the number of question in questionnaires?

---

### Json data

```
 {
   "id": 1,
   "status": "DRAFT",
   "title": "GAMES",
   "author": "foo",

   "questionnaires": [
          {
           "id": 1,
           "question": "Favorite game",
           "answers": [
                        "tongits",
                        "black jack",
                          "21"
                      ]
           },
         {
          "id": 2,
          "question": "game",
          "answers": [
                       "basketball",
                       "volleyball"
                     ]
          }
      ]
  }
```

### This is my code in VB

```
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList

For Each item As JProperty In results

item.CreateReader()
Select Case item.Name
    Case "questionnaires"
        Dim question As String
        For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
            listbox1.item.add(question)
        Next
End Select
Next
```

---

would gladly give thanks to whom will help

Comment: use `JObject.Parse(jsonstring)` then it is just `jobj("questionnaires")(0)("answers").ToArray()`

Comment: Alternatively, you could generate a typed class out of your JSON that you'd work against, with something like http://jsonutils.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo "questionnaire" since this doesn't exist in your JSON ("questionnaires" does). Also you don't need to search for it. Below is Javascript pseudo code you can reference. Should be pretty similar to VB.Net.

```
var jsonData = '{"id": 1,   "status": "DRAFT",  "title": "GAMES",   "author": "foo", "questionnaires": [          {          "id": 1,      "question": "Favorite game",           "answers": [                        "tongits",                        "black jack",                          "21"                      ]           },         {          "id": 2,          "question": "game",          "answers": [                       "basketball",                       "volleyball"                     ]          }      ]  }';    
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for (var question in jsonObj.questionnaires)
{
  console.log('ID:' + jsonObj.questionnaires[question].id);
  console.log('Question:' + jsonObj.questionnaires[question].question);
  for (var answerToQuestion in jsonObj.questionnaires[question].answers)
  {
    console.log('--->Answer:' + jsonObj.questionnaires[question].answers[answerToQuestion]);
  }
}
```

**Results:**

```
ID:1
Question:Favorite game
--->Answer:tongits
--->Answer:black jack
--->Answer:21
ID:2
Question:game
--->Answer:basketball
--->Answer:volleyball
```

Comment: thanks for the loop.
last question, how will you count the number of answer per question?

Comment: No need to count them since the answers are an array. Just use the length property on the array-> jsonObj.questionnairs [question].answers.length